# WiiMote turns off in Wii Shop Channel

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, wiimote

I have a Wii running system version 4.3U and two NYKO WAND WiiMote controllers. For some reason, when I open the Wii Shop Channel, the WiiMotes will instantly turn off. Attempting to turn them back on will only cause them to turn off again, and any further attempts will not return them to an on state. The console is not frozen and will cycle through the current offers and listings as usual.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? This is the only channel that causes this. If it matters any, my console is successfully softmodded.

Comment: It could be the third party controller, the soft mod, or even both of them. Does your original Wiimote still work?

Comment: I don't actually own an original WiiMote, sadly. That's why I had to get the NYKOs. The original broke when my dog decided to gnaw on it.

Comment: My third party controller did this after I soft moded my wii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using a first-party controller is the only way I can access the Wii Shop Channel at this point. I was gifted one as a present for my birthday which is how I found this out.

Not that it really matters, since the Wii Shop Channel is going down anyway.

Answer (score -3):

maby it's your wii motion plus. Do you have one in if not buy one put it in the bottom of the mote you can find them online or at a locale Walmart.

Comment: I don't own a WiiMotion+ addon, nor do I plan to buy one. If I wanted that I would just get a new controller. The NYKOs are only meh quality anyway. Too plastic-y.